# How can I upload files in Postman?

Tags: python, flask, postman

I want to pass images through POST method in POSTMAN but I get None type response in the line request.files['image']

I have tried a number of different things but I am not able to solve the problem.

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify
from flask import request
import face_recognition
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return ''


@app.route('/valid_faces', methods=['POST'])


def POST():
    if request.method == 'POST':

    # getting the images url from the request
    print('....')
    name1 = request.files['file'] if request.files.get('file') else None
    print('....')
    print (name1)        # name2 = request.form.get('name2')

    # map the url to the ones in the folder images
    firstImage = name1


    # loading the image inside a variable
    firstImage = face_recognition.load_image_file(firstImage)




    result=face_recognition.face_locations(firstImage)


    if result:
        # x={'valid_faces':True}
        # return jsonify(x)
        return "True"
    else:
        # x={'valid_faces':False}
        # return jsonify(x)
        return "False"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: try printing the `request` to investigate whats in it.

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: How are you posting the files? What does your request in Postman look like

Comment: I am posting the files by using key as 'image' and value as the file in form-data of POSTMAN

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wish to append a file to a postman call it needs to be added to the body.
Check `form-data` and select `file` instead of `text`. You can now select a file with the windows file explorer.

To obtain the given file use the `request` package.

```
file = request.files['file']
```

The index has to be the same string you specified within the postman body data.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' /  I am getting this error. The data has not been passed from POSTMAN to the flask app

Comment: @BivekGyawali could you provide me your module import?

Answer (score 3):

In Postman, do the following:

- Set the method to POST
- Set the body type to **form-data**
- Establish Key/Value pairs for input. Set the value for the Key to
  "file"
- Mouse over the Key field and choose Text or File from the drop-down
  menu
- Click Send to process the request

Answer (score 1):

follow this process: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGm4I.png

- Set Method to POST
- Change body tab to form-data
- Set key
- in Value, hover, you can see file/text. in here select file
- Select file you want to upload.
- Send request.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Postman set empty first value for FileStorage object in request.files . You can check this using:

```
print(str(request.files))
```

And in case of empty index instead

```
file = request.files['file']
```

try to use

```
file = request.files['']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it

```
 files = request.files.getlist("file")
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this syntax over that provided in the other answers? Are there benefits to using this in particular situations?

Comment: The other methods I wrote in the project I'm working on now are working. when i did it like that it started working fine